# Why this ADL case is working?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, argument-dependent-lookup

How does `find_type` know where the function `typemap` is?
The argument it receives is not from that namespace, it's from the `std` namespace!

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <memory>

namespace lib {
    template<typename T>
    struct find_type {
        using type = decltype(typemap(std::declval<T>()));
    };
}

namespace test {
    struct Test {};
    auto typemap(std::unique_ptr<Test>) -> int;    
}

static_assert(std::is_same<int, lib::find_type<std::unique_ptr<test::Test>>::type>::value, "");
```

How can this code work? What is the rule allowing this?

I tested it with GCC 6.3 and clang 3.9.1.

Comment: The parameter type of the template parameter `T` from the struct `find_type` is `std::unique_ptr<test::Test>`. `std::unique_ptr` considers the `test::Test` template parameter for ADL, and thus, finds the `typemap` function in the `test` NS

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the C++ standard N4618 §3.4.2 [basic.lookup.argdep] (2.2)

> If T is a class type (including unions), its associated classes are: the class itself; the class of which it is
>   a member, if any; and its direct and indirect base classes. Its associated namespaces are the innermost
>   enclosing namespaces of its associated classes. Furthermore, if T is a class template specialization,
>   its associated namespaces and classes also include: **the namespaces and classes associated with the
>   types of the template arguments provided for template type parameters** (excluding template template
>   parameters); the namespaces of which any template template arguments are members; and the classes
>   of which any member templates used as template template arguments are members.

The argument of `typemap` is `std::unique_ptr<test::Test>`, so namespace `test` is considered for name look up.

Answer (score 14):

> The argument it receives is not from that namespace, it's from the std namespace!

Not all of it!

```
using type = decltype(typemap(std::declval<T>()));
```

This is:

```
using type = decltype(typemap(std::declval<std::unique_ptr<test::Test>>()));
```

There's a `test::` in there, so the namespace `test` is searched too.